# Is there a skip duplicate entries for export-csv?

Tags: powershell

I have a query that fetches system data about a database

```
$data = Query "SELECT [server_name]
      ,[sessionID]
      ,[user]
      ,[ElapsedTime]
from table"
$data | Export-Csv -Path $Path\data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

recently ive noticed there are duplicate entries in the data exported, such as redundant session id. is there an option to export and skip duplicate entries?

something like

```
$data | Export-Csv -Path $Path\data.csv -NoTypeInformation -skipduplicates
```

for example, if the table has:

[image: table]

the exported csv should only contain:

[image: one entry]

i think some people may suggest i select distinct and avoid all this all together. but then how can i select distinct only the sessionID for example, because elapsed time is not unique for instance, so distinct shouldnt affect it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before exporting to `csv` you can use an additional pipe to exclude duplicates. You can add the properties on the basis of which you want to exclude the duplicates. Below is an example -

```
$data | Select-Object -Unique SessionId, User, ElapsedTime | Export-Csv -Path $Path\data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: what if elpsed time for example is the same in multiple entries, but those entries have say different users/session id's. would it also truncate them because one of the objects elapsed time is duplicated? or would it take the ENTIRE objects into account to make sure the whole entry is unique?

Comment: See the answer now. If you specify the properties by which you want to select unique rows, then it will take all the properties for all the objects into account to make sure the whole entry is unique.

Comment: this actually has an issue....elapsedtime is NOT unique. neither is user. the only thing that is primary key/unique and cant be repeated many times is sessionID. i just selected Select-Object -Unique SessionId and the file generated for me only the sessionID column...

Answer (score 1):

Another option to prevent duplicates is to add the GROUP BY clause to your SQL query:

```
SELECT [server_name]
      ,[sessionID]
      ,[user]
      ,MAX([ElapsedTime]) AS ElapsedTime 
from table 
GROUP BY [server_name],[sessionID],[user]
```

That will eliminate any rows with different ElapsedTime values that are otherwise duplicate.

Comment: wait but elapsed time could be different or duplicate. its not a problem. the only thing that has ot be unique is sessionID. sessionID entries cannot be duplicated

Comment: The query I provided will work if ElapsedTime is duplicate or not. It will return the larger ElapsedTime if there are multiple per session. If there are multiple [user] or [server_name] values per session you can take them out of the GROUP BY clause and use `MAX([user]) AS [user]` and `MAX([server_name]) as [server_name]` in the SELECT clause to ensure unique session rows.